# Reduce Build Time in React.js

Tags: reactjs, build, circleci

How to reduce the build time in React? Our application has around 150 components and it needs resource class to be large (higher ram) in circleci for the build process to work. If the resource class is set to small , the build fails with the following error. I did try code-splitting. But no luck. Is there a way to optimize react build and not increase the resource class?

> Creating an optimized production build... The build failed because the
> process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of
> memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your project, and there are many ways to reduce build time in React. I think you should first detect what is the cause of this, and you will have a starting point.

One helpful step could be using a package like [webpack bundle analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to examine the composition of your bundled JavaScript files. This tool generates visualizations that help you understand which parts of your code contribute the most to the overall bundle size.

Remember, identifying the problem is half the battle!